# Export Price Set Field Labels

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, price-sets

A customer of mine has a contribution page setup with a price set (different payroll options) and they have specific labels for each amount in the price set.

When I go in to pull a custom report, I don't see an option to pull the field label; is this possible to do?

[image]

Is it possible to include these labels in the custom report that we export?

Thank you!!

Comment: I am having the same issue and looks more like a bug in Civi, what has been missed is the Price Options Label in the Fee Level column. It can't be seen on any export method (else importing proper price set can't be done). The Fee Label can be seen in the preview of Participants under Fee Levels, e.g. My Price are Ballet and Tap, with options Grade 1, Grade 2, Grade 3. If some chooses Ballet - Grade 1 and another Tap - Grade 1 All I see when I export is Level 1 and Level 1. This data is not useful without the label. The only place that it displays properly is in the preview Search > Find Partic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the [extended reports extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) and investigate the options available to you in **Extended Report - Contributions with Price Set data**  or **Extended Report - Price Set Line Items**

Comment: JoAnne thanks so much for this answer - I found parts of the Fee Level info, including the Price Field Label field/column, in the Extended Report - Price Set Line Items - Template.